# ffmpeg failed to find a suitable output format

Tags: ffmpeg, node.js

I am using javascript to create a video file from several video files. I have an array in which I store my source video file and then use the following command and try to generate a single video:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a1.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a2.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a3.mkv  -filter_complex "[1]setpts=PTS+5.00/TB[a2];[2]setpts=PTS+10.00/TB[a3];[0][a2]overlay[o2];[o2][a3]overlay" with4.mp4
```

When I run the command in my console it runs perfectly, but I am using execFileSync to create the video from a javascript program,

```
let myString2 = '"' + string2;

let myString3 = string3 + '"';

let argsString = myString2 + myString3;
let myArgs = argsString.toString();

const createMasterStreams = execFileSync('ffmpeg', [string1, '-filter_complex', myArgs, masterOutFile]);
```

Contents of string1, string2 and string3 are as under:

```
string1: -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a1.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a2.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a3.mkv
string2: [1]setpts=PTS+5.00/TB[a2];[2]setpts=PTS+10.00/TB[a3];
string3: [0][a2]overlay[o2];[o2][a3]overlay
```

when I run the program I get the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0000026d8d77ad80] Unable to find a suitable output format for '"[1]setpts=PTS+5.00/TB[a2];[2]setpts=PTS+10.00/TB[a3];[0][a2]overlay[o2];[o2][a3]overlay"'
"[1]setpts=PTS+5.00/TB[a2];[2]setpts=PTS+10.00/TB[a3];[0][a2]overlay[o2];[o2][a3]overlay": Invalid argument
child_process.js:624
```

what am I doing wrong???

The following error shows that the double quotes around the arguments is missing:

```
Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a1.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a2.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a3.mkv  -filter_complex [1]setpts=PTS+5.00/TB[a2];[2]setpts=PTS+10.00/TB[a3];[0][a2]overlay[o2];[o2][a3]overlay with4.mp4
```

there should be double quotes after -filter_complex and should end before the output file. I tried using template literals as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder if it's related to the escaping of the `myArgs` value. Try removing the double quotes from your variable assignments.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The problem is with ffmpeg args which are inside the double quotes.

Comment: You didn't pass an output file to ffmpeg. Check the value of `masterOutFile`

Comment: the masterOutFile point to my object: let masterOutFile = userProject.finalOutputFileName; and the finaloutputfilename is set.

Comment: You should verify that. This message from `ffmpeg` is explained either by no output file or by `-filter_complex` being in the wrong place.

Comment: Just tested it...the filename for the output file is ok, for some reason the double quotes do not show up when the connad is run using execFileSync and this is trowing the whole thing off

Comment: what happens if you double up (or triple) the double quotes in your variables. Escape the double quotes.

Comment: I replaced my execFileSync code with template literals like so:

const createMasterStreams = execFileSync('ffmpeg', [string1, '-filter_complex', `"${string2}${string3}"`, userProject.finalOutputFileName]);

Now I get the double quotes around the arguments but still the same error. When I copy and run the command in shell it works perfectly but not from node.

Comment: What happens if you specify an output file, ignore `userProject.finalOutputFileName`. Specify an actual file.

Comment: Already tried that...gives the same error

Comment: I am using template literals so my double quotes are showing and not being escaped:
execFileSync('ffmpeg', [string1, '-filter_complex', `"${string2}${string3}" ${userProject.finalOutputFileName}`]);

I copied the console log output from this line of code and pasted it in my shell....works perfectly.

Comment: I removed the double quotes...now I get this error:

Output #0, mp4, to '[1]setpts=PTS+5.00/TB[a2];[2]setpts=PTS+10.00/TB[a3];[0][a2]overlay[o2];[o2][a3]overlay with4.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Comment: I acutally understand it. The difference between that issue and mine is that he was passing an arguments directly, while my arguments are stored in a variable (they need to be) and that variable is passed to the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Voting to migrate to Stack Overflow – this is a programming issue, nothing related to ffmpeg itself, or the command-line.

Comment: I agree. This seems to be going nowhere

Comment: I assume that "on the command line" this works?